# SQL Server : Using recursive CTE to resolve group membership

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, recursive-query

I have one table (`users_groups`) :

```
+-----------+------------+---------+
| groupGUID | memberGUID | isGroup |
+-----------+------------+---------+
|  32AB160C |   5B277276 |       0 |
|  32AB160C |   0A023D1D |       0 |
|  5C952B2E |   32AB160C |       1 |
|  4444FTG5 |   5C952B2E |       1 |
+-----------+------------+---------+
```

`isGroup` column indicates whether `memberGUID` is a group or not.

I want to obtain a new table (`new_users_groups`) with all group memberships resolved :

```
+-----------+------------+
| groupGUID | memberGUID |
+-----------+------------+
|  32AB160C |   5B277276 |
|  32AB160C |   0A023D1D |
|  5C952B2E |   5B277276 |
|  5C952B2E |   0A023D1D |
|  4444FTG5 |   5B277276 |
|  4444FTG5 |   0A023D1D |
+-----------+------------+
```

For now, I'm doing everything manually :

1. Looking for all group's memberGUID

   `SELECT * FROM users_groups WHERE isGroup = 1;`
2. For all groups returned by previous step, find its members

   `SELECT * FROM users_groups WHERE groupGUID = '5C952B2E'`
3. If members are not groups, insert them into a new table

   `INSERT INTO new_users_groups (groupGUID, memberGUID) VALUES ('5C952B2E', '5B277276');
    INSERT INTO new_users_groups (groupGUID, memberGUID) VALUES ('5C952B2E', '0A023D1D');`
4. If members are groups, go to step 2.

How can I automate this? Maybe with a Recursive CTE ?

Comment: It might help if you explain what the logic is for resolving memberships.  As of now, we would have to dig into your insert logic and try to tease that out.

Comment: Ok, I tried to be more explicit by adding an explanation for each step. It should be easier to understand for readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select ug.groupGUID, ug.groupGUID as grp, ug.memberGUID
  from user_groups ug
  where isGroup = 0
  union all
  select ug.groupGUID, ug.groupGUID as grp, cte.memberGUID
  from user_groups ug join
       cte
       on cte.grp = ug.memberGUID
 )
select groupGUID, memberGUID
from cte;
```

Here is a [Rextester](http://rextester.com/EYXHDF82394).

Answer (score 0):

Try `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT t1.groupGUID, t2.memberGUID 
FROM temp t1, temp t2 WHERE t2.isGroup = 0
GROUP BY t1.groupGUID, t2.memberGUID
```